# A question of Exercises

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, book-recommendation

I'm a math student, at the present time I am studying Theory of representation with the book, *Representation Theory of Finite Groups by Benjamin Steinberg*, but I have a problem, in my opinion, there are very few problems, apart of demonstrations. Can someone please give me one or more books where I can find some exercises (demonstrations and applications).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best books on Representation theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192721/best-books-on-representation-theory)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).